# PHP format() method of DateTime modifies time

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to display a dateTime with a specific format, but it modifies the time when displayed :

```
$opened_at = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2022-12-04 19:12:31');
$opened_at->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $opened_at->format('d/m/Y h:i');
```

I'm expecting this :

04/12/2022 **19:12**

But instead, I'm getting this :

04/12/2022 **08:12**

Why is that and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the time in Paris is meant by 19:12:31, this time zone must also be specified during creation. The specification can only be omitted if the default-timezone is already the desired timezone.

```
$opened_at = new \DateTime('2022-12-04 19:12:31',new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

echo $opened_at->format('d/m/Y H:i'); //04/12/2022 19:12
```

If the time zone is not specified during creation, the default time zone setting is used for the object and the time 19:12 is converted to the target time zone with setTimeZone. Depending on the default time zone, different times always result.

The following code therefore usually does not deliver the desired result:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$opened_at = new \DateTime('2022-12-04 19:12:31');
$opened_at->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

echo $opened_at->format('d/m/Y H:i'); //05/12/2022 01:12
```